# Container dependencies with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As a Jenkins pipeline user, I want to satisfy a dependency between a given stage (configured with Docker agent) and another container which runs a database service. Each stage of each build should run a different database container which will be destroyed after.

What is the cleanest way to do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into running "sidecar" containers?

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. My goal is to find a way to run/setup/clean the database container directly in the pipeline (in the Jenkinsfile).

Comment: Have you tried using the scripted syntax to run the docker commands that you want?

Comment: Indeed, this is something I was thinking about but that would be incompatible with the Jenkins agent. Furthermore, in this case I would be responsible of the containers life cycle which is something I want to avoid. Anyway thank you @ssc327 for sharing these ideas :)